# Finding the index of array in each grid cell?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a set of data. They are distributed in x-y positions but they have other characteristics like size. I like to grid my data in x-y plane and then obtain the grid index for each point and then compute the mean or standard deviation of size in each grid cell. I would like to see whether there is a correlation with the position in x-y plane with the size or not. The old fashion way is to write two loops and make a 3D matrix to keep the index of data in each cell. I am wondering whether there is a class in numpy or python which does this?

I know I can use `np.histogram2d` but it just returns the number of points in each grid but not the index of array in each point or `matplotlib.mlab.griddata` somehow interpolate between the grid cells but I don't want any interpolation. I am just interested to get the index of points in each grid cell.

```
xmin=min(Xpos);xmax=max(Xpos)
ymin=min(Ypos);ymax=max(Ypos)
ngridx = 10
ngridy = 10

xi = np.linspace(np.floor(xmin),np.ceil(xmax),ngridx)
yi = np.linspace(np.floor(ymin),np.ceil(ymax),ngridy)
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(Ypos, Xpos, bins=(xi, yi), normed=False)
```

The output from `np.histogram2d` looks like this:

```
>>>H
array([[  17.,  114.,  301.,  321.,  308.,  163.,  171.,  298.,  316.],
       [ 223.,  211.,  291.,  323.,  282.,  195.,  263.,  198.,  174.],
       [ 304.,  312.,  322.,  295.,  218.,  295.,  259.,  209.,   80.],
       [ 204.,  260.,  298.,  261.,  296.,  241.,   47.,  133.,  189.],
       [ 270.,  265.,  245.,  265.,  286.,  236.,  108.,  214.,  275.],
       [ 276.,  198.,  275.,  235.,  261.,  267.,  223.,  306.,  282.],
       [ 246.,   60.,   88.,  189.,  259.,  225.,  302.,  306.,  328.],
       [ 292.,  138.,    0.,  141.,  297.,  308.,  314.,  276.,  317.],
       [ 169.,  203.,   67.,  220.,  261.,  306.,  329.,  250.,  277.]])
```

But I would like to get the index in each grid cell. I am looking fir the fastest way to do it.
I came up with this idea. I don't know whether it is the best way to go or not:

```
for i in range(len(xi)-1):
    for j in range(len(yi)-1):
        bxlow=(Xpos>xi[i]); bxup=(Xpos<=xi[i+1])
        bx=bxlow*bxup
        bylow=(Ypos>yi[j]); byup=(Ypos<=yi[j+1])
        by=bylow*byup
        bprim=bx*by
```

using `bprim` to distinguish data in the grids.
any better suggestion?

Comment: Could you also show some code with progress that you have made so we can understand your question better?

Comment: Please show some code with an example ...

Comment: Why not simply calculate the correlation between x,y and size variables?

Comment: @sshashank124 It is a big data set and I would like to do it in the fastest way because there are a lot of properties I would like to do statistics on them. Small piece of code is added.

Comment: @gnocalopp I don't understand how it can be done?

Comment: @Dalek You may want to check out [numpy.corrcoef](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) or [scipy.stats.pearsonr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html)

Comment: I don't know if it does all the things you want, but scipy.stats has analogs to numpy's histogram functions that let you calculate statistics for each cell, see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html

Comment: Thanks @user333700! It does the job!! That is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for numpy.indices?

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html

something like:

```
 row, col = np.indices( H.shape )
```

will get you what you want.

or, you may want the x,y coordinates? In that case,

```
np.meshgrid(xi,yi)
```